# ActiveMQ Artemis HA & users/roles - am I supposed to create user/role on each node separately?

Tags: high-availability, activemq-artemis

I have ActiveMQ Artemis cluster (2 nodes) with active-backup HA (shared-store mode), 2.17.0.

Shared-store is setup with NFS, mounted on `$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE/data`. In `broker.xml` I specified the following settings - pretty standard:

```
      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
```

---

According to this [official documentation page](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html), there is `login.conf` file in `etc` directory which specifies users & roles files. I have the following contents:

```
activemq {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";
};
```

Well, everything seem to work fine with it, but I noticed that every time I want to create a new user/role, I have to create twice, in each node separately. If I have replication HA mode and 6 nodes, I would need to create the same user/role 6 times (for each node).

**Am I not missing anything here?**

---

Then I've come up with an idea to literally move `artemis-users.properties` and `artemis-roles.properties` to a `$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE/data` directory and modify `login.conf` file accordingly, so I can create user/role only once, and created entries will be accessible from other node(s):

```
activemq {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="../data/artemis-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="../data/artemis-roles.properties";
};
```

Since this is shared store, it kind of makes sense for me to store this way. I did quite some testing and everything seems to work fine, I do not think there are going to be any race conditions this way.

**Again, am I not missing anything? Any suggestions/better workarounds?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PropertiesLoginModule` is provided by default because it is simple and straight-forward to configure for basic use-cases. However, it's not really designed for production use across a cluster. Typically you'd use an LDAP server (or some equivalent) which is a central store for all your user & role data. As [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#propertiesloginmodule) states:

> In general, using properties files and broker-centric user management for anything other than very basic use-cases is not recommended. The broker is designed to deal with messages. It's not in the business of managing users, although that functionality is provided at a limited level for convenience. LDAP is recommended for enterprise level production use-cases.

You are, of course, free to use the `PropertiesLoginModule` in more complex use-cases (e.g. like yours). I think putting the properties files on shared storage is fine and not likely to lead to problems.